# Python: How to use MFdataset in netCDF4

Tags: python, netcdf, netcdf4

I am trying to read multiple NetCDF files and my code returns the error:

> ValueError: MFNetCDF4 only works with NETCDF3_* and NETCDF4_CLASSIC formatted files, not NETCDF4.

I looked up the documentation and MFdataset is not supported by NetCDF4, so I'm confused where to go from here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the error is pretty clear, but there are ways to avoid it.

1/ You could convert the NetCDF files from NetCDF4 to the classic format using e.g. [nccopy](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/workshops/2011/utilities/Nccopy.html):

```
nccopy -k classic nc4_file.nc ncclassic_file.nc
```

2/ [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/) has a similar method (called `open_mfdataset`) which is able to handle NetCDF4 files. A quick test:

```
import netCDF4 as nc4
test = nc4.MFDataset(['test0.nc','test1.nc'])
```

This gives me the same error as you get (*"MFNetCDF4 only works with..."*), the same with xarray works without any problems:

```
import xarray as xr
test = xr.open_mfdataset(['test0.nc', 'test1.nc'])
```