# Issues reading NetCDF4 LST files from Copernicus

Tags: netcdf4

I have a series of hourly LST data from [Copernicus](https://land.copernicus.eu/global/products/lst). These can be read and displayed fine in Panopoly (Windows version 4.10.6) but:

- Crash QGIS 2.18.13 when opening with the 'NetCDF4 Browser' plugin (V0.3)
- Reads LST variable incorrectly using R ncdf4 code:

*

```
file1 <- nc_open('g2_BIOPAR_LST_201901140400_E114.60S35.43E119.09S30.22_GEO_V1.2.nc')
file2 <- nc_open('g2_BIOPAR_LST_201901140500_E114.60S35.43E119.09S30.22_GEO_V1.2.nc')
# attributes(file1)$names
# Just for one variable for now
dat_new <- cbind(
  ncvar_get(file1, 'LST'),
  ncvar_get(file2, 'LST'))
dim(dat_new)
print(dim(dat_new))
var <- file1$var['LST']$LST
# Create a new file
file_new <- nc_create(
  filename = 'Copernicus_LST.nc', 
  # We need to define the variables here
  vars = ncvar_def(
    name = 'LST',
    units = var$units,
    dim = dim(dat_new)))

# And write to it
ncvar_put(
  nc = file_new,
  varid = 'LST',
  vals = dat_new)
# Finally, close the file
nc_close(file_new)
```

Returns:

```
[1] "Error, passed variable has a dim that is NOT of class ncdim4!"
[1] "Error occurred when processing dim number 1 of variable LST"
Error in ncvar_def(name = "LST", units = var$units, dim = dim(dat_new)) : 
  This dim has class: integer
```

Similarly, using the python netCDF4 approach

```
compiled = netCDF4.MFDataset(['g2_BIOPAR_LST_201901140400_E114.60S35.43E119.09S30.22_GEO_V1.2.nc','g2_BIOPAR_LST_201901140500_E114.60S35.43E119.09S30.22_GEO_V1.2.nc']))
```

Returns

```
ValueError: MFNetCDF4 only works with NETCDF3_* and NETCDF4_CLASSIC formatted files, not NETCDF4
```

I'm presuming that this is an issue with the file formatting from Copernicus... Has anyone else encountered this? Have put these [two example files here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qkm0htid1410bg6/AAAeIlN2R_YjvxNQY86qXORMa?dl=0).

Thanks!

Comment: For Python, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51290858/python-how-to-use-mfdataset-in-netcdf4

Comment: Thanks Bart. Certainly a good workaround! I tried downloading a few global files and they worked fine with all of the libraries. So the moral is when downloading data from Copernicus, don't bother restricting the area to you area of interest!

Comment: So with global data, you don't get NetCDF4?

Comment: You get NetCDF4 for global requests and it loads in fine to QGIS and the RStudio and Python NetCDF4 libraries.